# Library or approach to extract RGB channels values in RAW image

Tags: c++, image-processing, decoding, bmp, bitmapimage

I'm searching for a solution for image comparison for different purposes.
To make it possible to analyze, I need access to every pixel channels values.
For example: RAW format which supported by a lot of cameras.

*
Is there some open source library to get access to channels,
or is it possible to extract it directly as byte values?
*
Currently I'm using bitmap_image reader (https://github.com/ArashPartow/bitmap), but not a good idea to convert everytime raw image bo BMP to analyze, I've related [repo added to github](https://github.com/MaksymT17/aquamarine), it kind of library written on C++14

Please suggest fastest way to access to data of image, thanks.

Comment: ffmpeg? Or opencv? Have you tried anything yourself? Also, what raw format do you mean, there are a few available, apparently?

Comment: [I`m not expert] but format from usual quality cameras, as far as I know its near to losseless and named RAW. JPEG for example have a lot of compression to reduce file size - its not a good format from quality perspective.
Pam, you suggest ffmpeg ?      thanks for reply

Comment: It depends...JPEG can be lossless, in which case it’s entirely reversible and as good as a bmp. But the only way to tell would be to get both things from the camera and compare, or look at the JPEG bitstream. I haven’t used ffmpeg for raw to bmp conversion but it would be my first port of call (I don’t have ImageMagick by default).

Answer (score 3):

Use **ImageMagick** which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows.

At the command-line:

```
# Convert NEF raw file to 16-bit RGB data
magick image.nef -depth 16 rgb:image.bin

# Convert CR2 raw file to 8-bit RGB data
magick image.cr2 -depth 8 rgb:image.bin
```

Or use it with `popen()` in C/C++ and have it write on `stdout`:

```
magick image.dng -depth 16 rgb:-
```

and then read in C/C++.

---

If you want to identify the dimensions of an image before reading:

```
magick identify temp.png
temp.png PNG 640x480 640x480+0+0 8-bit Gray 2c 12348B 0.000u 0:00.009
```

---

If using version 6, replace `magick` with `convert`, and replace `magick identify` with `identify`.

---

Alternatively, look at NetPBM `PPM` format (see `P6` format [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format))
and develop some code to read it then just convert anything and everything into `PPM` format with **ImageMagick** and read that, which gives you the dimensions at the start:

```
magick image.nef -depth 16 ppm:-
magick image.cr2 -depth 8  ppm:-
```

Note that this is exactly the strategy adopted by [CImg](http://cimg.eu).

Comment: and I can access to them one-by-one RGB->RGB... ?
do you have some sources links with examples?
in adv. thanks Mark

Comment: but it looks like I`ll use system call(to run tooll magick/netPBM) to convert from RAW to other format then I need to then extract bytes, 
its not possible to extract values directly with open file in c++ ?

Comment: That is possible, but then you'll have to learn the `Magick++` library and compile and link with it - which is possible but has a much steeper learning curve. Put `[magick++]` in the StackOverflow search box for examples.

Comment: I was suggesting you use `popen()` rather than `system()` then you just read from a pipe without having to create a temporary file on disk.

Comment: Note that you will need the `dcraw` or `ufraw` libraries installed where ImageMagick can find them if you want to read NEF/CR2/DNG files.

Comment: sorry but, it not work I`ve installed as you wrote,
download  dng sample
affter convert command: I`ve got some unexpected symbols(no file converted), seems it is some error or exception. Needed 100% tool or library.
console:

convert L1004220.DNG -depth 16 rgb:-
r7p....

Comment: First, try converting to a simple JPEG with `convert image.dng result.jpg`. Then try converting to binary RGB data with `convert image.dng rgb:result.dat`. If you are using `popen()` like I suggested write in PPM format on stdout with `convert image.dng PPM:-` That will write lots of binary stuff on your Terminal because that is what you are supposed to read from the `popen()` pipe.

Comment: If you want to make a binary PPM file to look at, use `convert image.dng result.ppm`.  If you want to make an ASCII PPM file to look at, use `convert image.dng -compress none result.ppm`